# How to pass the current view to a called method of the view model?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I need to trim a text in my `TextInputEditText` after its text was changed. In short I need a something like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/label_title"
    android:text="@{ model.name }"
    android:maxLength="256"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:afterTextChanged="@{(s) -> model::afterNameChanged(this, s)}"
    app:validateEmpty="@{true}"
    app:validateEmptyMessage="@{@plurals/error_too_short(1, 1)}"
    app:validateEmptyAutoDismiss="@{true}"/>
```

And then in my view model:

```
class TimetableEditorViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    var name = ObservableString("")

    fun afterNameChanged(view: TextInputEditText, s: Editable) {
        view.setText(s.trim())
    }
}
```

**Is it possible in the Android data binding framework?**

Comment: yes you can do that. Also, this is the correct approach you are doing. Is this not working?

Comment: @karandeepsingh, honestly, I have written it for sample just, I was sure it hasn't `this`, so I didn't try even =) But in any case I wanted to know also whether it's a good idea to put my handler in the view model.

Answer (score 1):

You can very much do that in android databinding framework. In your edit text in xml, `android:afterTextChanged="@{model::afterTextChanged}"`. 
And in your view model

```
    fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
    if (editable.isNotEmpty()) {
       //Set your name variable here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't, my listener is located in the view model. The model can't hold a reference to the view, it can produce memory leaks. Of course, I can use `WeakReference` but it is a dirty hack, imho.

Comment: where in my code you can see there a reference of the view? there is no reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `this` keyword in data binding. Instead  you can set value of `name` in `afterNameChanged` method.

```
fun afterNameChanged(view: TextInputEditText, s: Editable) {
    name.set(s.trim().toString())
}
```

But if you do this, user will not be able to enter space in his name. because spaces will be trimmed.

You can also use [two-way data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way). This will update name in model when user type something. You can trim name in setter of name.

```
android:text="@={model.name}"
```

But same issue will be there, user will not be able to enter space.

So you should just trim name when you are setting it programatically.

Comment: I don't need to the user could input spaces. And unfortunately, I can't use two-way binding due to the data validation. Seems it validates data before the model will be updated from code. So the validator sees that the field has `"<space>"` text, it's not empty... that means all right.

Comment: You should trim text in your validator